# How to enable quick edit in an External List?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, data-view-web-part, external-content-type

I know, it is not supported. I am in the process to customize a ECT list view with access to enable the quick edit function.

Comment: Hi David, did you find a way to solve this issue? Thank you